# 1 does not == 1, boolean issue

Tags: java, boolean

Am I going crazy or something, or do I need more sleep... can annyone offer a second set of eyes please?

```
boolean slotTypeMatch = false;
System.out.println("waiType: " + waiType);
if (waiType.equals("W")){

} else if(waiType.equals("A")){
    itemFilename = MyServer.armorMap.get(waiId).getFilename();
    System.out.println("endContainerSlot: " + endContainerSlot + ", getSlot: " + MyServer.weaponMap.get(waiId).getSlot());
    if (endContainerSlot == MyServer.armorMap.get(waiId).getSlot()){
        System.out.println("WHY DONT I MAKE IT HERE!!!!");
        slotTypeMatch = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("itemFilename: " + itemFilename);
System.out.println("slotTypeMatch: " + slotTypeMatch);
if (slotTypeMatch){
    //not making it here, I must be going insane
```

And here is my console output... I can't figure this out for the life of me...

```
waiType: A 
endContainerSlot: 1, getSlot: 1
itemFilename: images/armor/armor_tunic.png 
slotTypeMatch: false
```

Edit they are both int

```
int endContainerSlot - com.jayavon.game.server.MyCommandHandler.run()
int com.jayavon.game.actualgame.Armor.getSlot()
```

Comment: Are they of the same type?

Comment: yes sorry they are both int

Comment: What is the data type of endContainerSlot and getSlot ?

Comment: what kind of datatype you are comparing??

Comment: they are both int, I have edited, sorry for leaving out the obvious

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is it multithreaded app ?

Comment: Please review your edits before posting them, and use code formatting on snippets and I/O as well.

Comment: I was mid edit when you locked the post with your edits, sorry, as I mentioned its been a long night.  Thanks for the help, I know it was a dumb question, but I'de appreciate the downpost to be removed.  Thanks

Comment: StackExchange AI alert: Detected "programmer too tired and making silly mistakes" - vote to close as "too localized" initiated ... with "go to bed" option.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You output `MyServer.weaponMap`, but you are comparing `endContainerSlot` to `MyServer.armorMap`. 
I think you wanted to either compare to `weaponMap` or you are doing the right comparison but looking at the wrong map in the output.

Comment: AHHHHH thanks a million, I'm officially going to bed.  Sorry to waste your guys time... will accept in 9 mins when it lets me, then bed

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("endContainerSlot: " + endContainerSlot + ", getSlot: " + MyServer.weaponMap.get(waiId).getSlot());
if (endContainerSlot == MyServer.armorMap.get(waiId).getSlot()){
    System.out.println("WHY DONT I MAKE IT HERE!!!!");
    slotTypeMatch = true;
}
```

Your comparing different maps here, armorMap vs weaponMap, i think that is you problem...

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, thanks a million

Answer (score 3):

`MyServer.armorMap` & `MyServer.weaponMap` is different. I think you should update your code and get some sleep. :)

```
if (endContainerSlot == MyServer.weaponMap.get(waiId).getSlot()){...}
```